# How to bundle components for the current loading page in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created two components named Home and About.What I have done is bundling components into a single file named 'bundle.js'. As my understanding on load it will bundle Home and About both components into 'bundle.js'.What I want is on initial load just to bundle the components for Home page only and on requesting About Page, components related to it will be bundled.

I am using webpack and react-router for routing.

Comment: You are asking for `codesplitting`. Read more at webpack to achieve this https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: @Panther It will be helpfull if you provide a link to sample for that.

Comment: You may check some simple tutorial here https://hackernoon.com/straightforward-code-splitting-with-react-and-webpack-4b94c28f6c3f https://medium.com/@puppybits/webpack-code-splitting-by-routes-92f96cf733f2